# How to set environment variable in Linux permanently

Tags: linux, environment-variables

How I can set the new environment variables and their value permanently in Linux

I used `export` to set the env variables. But the problem is its session specific. If I open new session the values set will be gone.
Thank you in advance

Comment: put them into /etc/environ and reboot. However, some services may run with a *clean* environment though. that depends on the service

Comment: Set it in your `~/.bashrc` for bash or `~/.zshrc`  for zsh.

Comment: @dlmeetei This would be shell specific then. /etc/environ is the right place

Comment: @hek2mgl, correct. Those are just examples. I did not answer as this should go to superuser and no need to reboot. Just `sudo source /etc/environ`

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables)

Comment: @dlmeetei Again wrong. The source command would just affect the current shell. sudo source would affect nothing

Comment: @hek2mgl Your next launch of terminal will have `/etc/environ` invoke automatically. Also, setting system wide environ is not a good idea

Comment: @dlmeetei Would you explain why you think that setting system wide environment variables is not a good idea?

Comment: @hek2mgl Why to clutter other users' environ who does not need it or May be another user need same variable for different value

Comment: That user can override it. That's the idea

Comment: Let the user decide what he need. I don't want to override

Comment: If a user wants an environment variable to be set he will use `export VAR=VALUE` regardless if it has been set system-wide or not. There is zero difference between setting and overriding a variable. Also there is zero negative effect in setting an environment variable system wide or not. Not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: Preferences differ from person to person. I don't want mine to be cluttered. Do you enjoy your backyard to be cluttered by somebody else?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to set a variable in your shell (as opposed to the superuser's):

1. Make sure your `.bashrc` exists

```
ls -A ~/.bashrc
```

2. Add your variable at the bottom

```
export VARIABLE=value
```

3. Save, then open a new terminal and verify the variable is set

```
$ echo $VARIABLE
value
```

Keep in mind this depends on your shell.

Comment: In point 4, it would be good to add that the .bashrc needs to be reloaded, using : "source .bashrc" , considering you are in the same cwd of .bashrc.

Comment: nice @PedroGomes +1

Comment: @PedroGomes excellent point,
   
marcdahan I think you should edit your answer and add his suggestion

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**: In order to export and keep environment variables persistent on linux you should export variables decelration into one of the following files: `~/.bash_profile` / `~/. bash_login` / `~/.profile`.

When bash is invoked as an interactive/non-interactive login shell, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile` (if exists) and after looks for these following files ( in that order and do the same)  `~/.bash_profile`, `~/. bash_login`, `~/.profile`.

**Example:** adding secret token into ***my*** user profile.

```
cat << End >> ~/.profile
export SECRET_TOKEN=abc123!@#
End
```

output:

```
echo $SECRET_TOKEN
abc123!@#
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual place is `~/.bashrc` assuming that you're using bash, which is the default in most distributions. Check yourself with `echo $SHELL`.
You may use `~/.bash_profile`, if you only want to set the variable in login shells (but i.e. not in scripts).

Comment: Its bash. only problem is I dont have access to any of the files ~/.bash_profile,.bashrc,/etc/environment. Is it still possible to set the path using command which will not be depend on session?

Comment: If you haven't even access to files in ``$HOME`` you will need to set them each time again or include in any scripts anyway. if you have some path like ``/myapp/`` writable you can use ``/myapp/vars`` and include ``source /myapp/vars`` into your scripts. (Take care of syntax errors in vars, which will be included in your scripts!)

Answer (score 1):

there's a good explanation of when to put it where here :
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html
if you don't have root access put it somewhere local like .bash_profile or depending on which shell you use. Find your shell by typing the command ps .

Answer (score 1):

This is working inside Debian 11. It should work on other Debian based distributions like Ubuntu etc. I am using the old school nano to edit the file named `pam_env.conf` that resides in `/etc/security/` directory, you may use whatever else you want instead of nano.

`sudo nano /etc/security/pam_env.conf`

Format for setting the environment variable inside this file is following:

`VARIABLE   [DEFAULT=[value]]  [OVERRIDE=[value]]`

(For example, let's set `DXVK_HUD` variable with the value `full`. This is equivalent to `export DXVK_HUD=full` You can replace the variable name and it's value to whatever you want for your use cases.)

This is how it is going to look inside that file as a new line:

`DXVK_HUD  DEFAULT=full  OVERRIDE=full`

Make the changes by saving it ( CTRL+O key combination is used for making changes through nano). Then press return (Enter key). And then press CTRL+X to exit from nano.

Restart your system. And type `env` in Terminal and see if you can see your environment variable in the list. It should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Set it in `/etc/environment`. In my Ubuntu installation this is the place where you can set environment variables persistently. The file may be different for a different distribution. Following is the contents of my `/etc/environment` file.

`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

See how the environment variable `PATH` is being set above.

***A note on export command***

`export varname` makes variable `varname` available to any subshell run from the your current shell, i.e. the shell on which you ran the `export` command. Any other shell, which is either unrelated to your current shell or is a parent will not have this variable. Knowing this, assuming you are using bash shell, you can write the export command in `.bashrc` file. `.bashrc` is a file which is run every time a bash shell is started, and hence any command you write in it gets executed in any bash shell opened. Thus writing the export command in the `.bashrc` file is another option. Similar will be the process for any other shell you are using. for eg. for Z shell the file is .zshrc.

Comment: Its bash. only problem is I dont have access to any of the files ~/.bash_profile,.bashrc,/etc/environment. Is it still possible to set the path using command which will not be depend on session?

Comment: How are you accessing the session? via ssh?
Also, update your question with this requirement of yours. It will highly influence the answer.

Comment: Hi Sahil, My requirement is I have a load generating machine with minimal access to the folder. I want to set the environment variable so that I can parametrise the test data path.

Comment: What is a generating machine?