# What does this command do 'GOFLAGS=-mod=mod'?

Tags: go, yaml, backend, go-cobra, go-build

I am trying to make a Taskfile.yml file for building go application, but I can't quite understand the need of "GOFLAGS=-mod=mod" command before go build main.go.

reference: https://dev.to/aurelievache/learning-go-by-examples-part-3-create-a-cli-app-in-go-1h43

Comment: The purpose of that is to insert a temporary GOFLAGS variable into the environment with the value ```-mod=mod```  just for the build environment.  Something akin to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502996/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-linux-permanentlybut without the need to using ```EXPORT```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So there are two things here

- `GOFLAGS`

  - this is nothing but an environment variable(if you don't understand what an environment variable is, think of it like a value that can be accessed by any process in your current environment. These values are maintained by the OS).
  - So this `GOFLAGS` variable has a space separated list of flags that will automatically be passed to the appropriate go commands.
  - The flag we are setting here is `mod`, this flag is applicable to the `go build` command and may not be applicable to other go commands.
  - If you are curious how `go` does this, [refer to this change request](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/126656/4)
  - Since we are mentioning this as part of the command, this environment variable is temporarily set and is not actually exported.
- what does setting `-mod=mod` flag, actually do during `go build`?

  - The `-mod` flag controls whether go.mod may be automatically updated and whether the vendor directory is used.
  - `-mod=mod` tells the go command to ignore the vendor directory and to automatically update go.mod, for example, when an imported package is not provided by any known module.
  - [Refer this](https://go.dev/ref/mod#build-commands).

Therefore

```bash
GOFLAGS="-mod=mod" go build main.go
```

is equivalent to

```bash
go build -mod=mod main.go
```